# How can I conditionally stop a SAS script from executing without sending an error message to the log?

Tags: sas

I want to have something like this, but I don't want an error message to be sent to the SAS log when it exits.

```
data test_table;
     input numbers;
     datalines;
1
2
3
4
5
;
run ;

proc sql;
     select count(*) into :recordsCount
     from test_table;
quit;

%macro abortIfRemaining;
     %if (&recordsCount > 0) %then %do;
           %abort return 0;
     %end;

     %put No records found;
%mend abortIfRemaining;

* More code blocks would go here if no records found ;

%abortIfRemaining;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the command I was looking for. It was "endsas".

```
data test_table;
     input numbers;
     datalines;
1
2
3
4
5
;

proc sql;
     select count(*) into :recordsCount
     from test_table;
quit;

%macro abortIfRemaining;
     %if (&recordsCount > 0) %then %do;
           endsas;
     %end;

     %put No records found;
%mend abortIfRemaining;

* More code blocks would go here if no records found ;

%abortIfRemaining;
```